# I am playing a quiz and I want to make new user if the user is not there in the database

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a quiz module in which there is only one user for now. So if the new user plays a quiz then the user will be added to the database and if the existed user is playing the quiz the we just have to update the coins

I have made a logic but it doesn't works for me

```php
public function story1_home_coin(Request $request)
{
    $coins = $request->input('coins');
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $activity_users = activity_users::all();
    $found = false;
    foreach($activity_users as $activity_user){
        if($user_id == $sctivity_user->user_id)
        {
            $found= true;
        }
        else{
            $found = false;
        }
    }
    if($found = true){
        activity_users::where([
            ['user_id', '=', $user_id],
            ['activity_id', '=', 1]
        ])->update(['coins' => $coins]);
    }
    else{
        $newactivity_users = new activity_users;
        $newactivity_users->userid = $user_id;
        $newactivity_users->activity_id = 1;
        $newactivity_users->coins = $coins;
        $newactivity_users->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have fixed my error I got a spelling mistake on line 8 in above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic should be like this:

```
public function story1_home_coin(Request $request)
{
    $coins = $request->input('coins');
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $activity_users = activity_users::where('user_id',$user_id);

        if($activity_users->count()){
            activity_users::where([
               ['user_id', '=', $user_id],
               ['activity_id', '=', 1]
            ])->update(['coins' => $coins]);
        }else{
            $newactivity_users = new activity_users;
            $newactivity_users->userid = $user_id;
            $newactivity_users->activity_id = 1;
            $newactivity_users->coins = $coins;
            $newactivity_users->save();
        }
}
```

In your logic, you are checking the user by looping on to the data after fetching all the data, while you should only fetch the related user.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code that lead to an unexpected behaviour.

First, in your foreach-loop, you're not dropping out of the loop when you have found a matching user_id, hence you're (almost) always setting `$found` to false.

For example, if you're looking for user_id 3, you'd go through your users 1-5.

1. user_id == 1 -> $found = false
2. user_id == 2 -> $found = false
3. user_id == 3 -> $found = true
4. user_id == 4 -> $found = false
5. user_id == 5 -> $found = false

This can be resolved by using a `break;` in your loop, like this:

```php
foreach($activity_users as $activity_user){
    if($user_id == $sctivity_user->user_id)
    {
        $found= true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Second problem is the line where you check the `$found` variable. You're actually not *checking* the variable, you're *setting* the variable:

```
if($found = true){
```

compared to this

```
if($found == true){
```